# Angularjs: too much recursion error on custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know if i should worry about this, i have been making a custom directive which dispatches a click event on a `input[type="file"]` when a `div` is clicked, everytime a file is chosen or the file selector dialog is closed the error shows in the console.

directive.js

```
module.directive("cropper", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "components/cropper/cropper-directive.html",
        link: link 
    };

    function link(scope, element, attr){
        var selector = element[0].querySelector(".cropper-selector");
        var input = element[0].querySelector(`input[type="file"]`);

        // Trigger file input select when selector detects a click
        selector.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
            var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                bubbles: true,
                canceable: true
            }, false);

            input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        });
    }
});
```

directive.html

```
<div class="cropper">
    <div class="cropper-image">
        <div class="cropper-selector">
            <label class="centered">Click or drop an image on this block</label>
            <input type="file"></input>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cropper-actions"></div>
</div>
```

i have searched for solutions but all of the threats i have found are made only on `jQuery` and as you can see, i am using the native event listeners of `Javascript`, if this is something i should worry about, i would like to know the solution without using any `jQuery` method

**UPDATE**: i've forgot to mention that `input` has `display: none` so it would make the component look like a draggable drop files

Comment: I'm just wondering if `input` clicked -> `cropper-selector` also clicked?

Comment: @grepLines no, sorry for not showing that `input` has display `none`, i will update that

Comment: no I mean if you set the `input` to a click event, then it also means that `cropper-selector` also trigger that clicked? this causes recursion

Comment: @grepLines sorry, input has no programmed click listener rather than the default which is triggered from the container's click event

Comment: have you tried the solution below? Is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selector.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true, //<----
        canceable: true
    }, false);

    input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
});
```

your `click` event bubbles up to `.cropper-selector` and triggers there another `click` event wich causes another `input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);` wich again bubbles up, and so on and so forth.

Do you know, that if you set your markup up like the following, you can get rid of the whole function `link()` and all it does?

```
<label class="cropper-selector">
    <div class="centered">Click or drop an image on this block</div>
    <input type="file"></input>
</label>
```

Comment: i had no idea about `bubbles` stuff, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Option 1: change html slightly

```
   <div class="cropper-image">
        <div class="cropper-selector">
            <label class="centered">Click or drop an image on this block</label>
       </div>
       <!--new div-->
       <div>
            <input type="file"></input>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Option 2: Changes to your script

```
    selector.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
            bubbles: true,
            canceable: true
        }, false);

        input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        event.stopPropagation(); //**add this line**
    });
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sorry for answering late, i had issues with network.. I have tried your first option before and yet somehow that triggers the same error, also i have tried your second option and still the error shows up, luckily the other answer did solve the problem and i understood how this works better